# Can I add an if statement to a parameter?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to add an if statement into a function parameter? For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    bool Example = false;
    Console.Write((if(!Example){"Example is false"}else{"Example is true"}));
}
//Desired outcome of when the code shown above is
//executed would be for the console to output:
//Example is false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the *[conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)* or *ternary* operator `?:`:

Its form is

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

For example:

```
Console.Write((!Example) ? "Example is false" : "Example is true");
```

Or my personal preference,

```
Console.Write(Example ? "Example is true" : "Example is false");
```

so that I never have to think what happens when "not `Example` is false".

Note that you cannot put arbitrary code for `value_if_true` and `value_if_false` -- it has to be an *expression*, not a statement. So the above is valid because

```
(!Example) ? "Example is false" : "Example is true"
```

is a `string`, you can write:

```
string message = (!Example) ? "Example is false" : "Example is true";
Console.Write(message);
```

However, you cannot do

```
(!Example) ? Console.Write("Example is false") : Console.Write("Example is true")
```

for example, because `Console.Write(..)` does not return a value, or

```
(!Example) ? { a = 1; "Example is false" } : "Example is true"
```

because `{ a = 1; "Example is false" }` is not an expression.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for the [ternary expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

```
if (thisIsTrue)
   Console.WriteLine("this")
else
   Console.WriteLine("that")
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Console.WriteLine(thisIsTrue ? "this" : "that")
```

Comment: If you're a fan of convoluted code, you'll be happy to know that you can nest ternary expressions infinitely. `var x = thisIsTrue ? 1 : thatIsTrue ? 2 : 3` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write(Example?"Example is true":"Example is false");
```

or even

```
Console.Write("Example is " + (Example?"True":"False"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Pardon the air code, I'm using a tablet.

You can do what you want with the ternary operator (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), as follows...

```
Console.Write(!Example?"Example is false":"Example is true");
```

Basically, this acts like an inline "if" statement. If the part before the question mark is true, then you get the bit between the question mark and colon. If false, you get the bit after the colon.

If that doesn't make sense, post back and I'll try to provide a clearer example when I'm on a real computer.